# How to use the @RenderBody()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I got a template on the internet and implemented it successfully in my mvc root project. However when I put @Renderbody () ... in the zone where I put it, it does a "rendering" of the official microsoft template and the original one from when we created an MVC project.
Can someone tell me why this happens?

[image: Layout RenderBody()]

[image: what happens]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the point of using @RenderBody in a MVC Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322458/whats-the-point-of-using-renderbody-in-a-mvc-razor-view) and [What to do with @RenderBody()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789674/what-to-do-with-renderbody)

Comment: I am not realizing ... I do not use renderbody () the program does not run ... if I use it, it appears to me. my code is divided into sections

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Razor, there are two kinds of views: regular .cshtml files and and *layouts*, that (not same as with ASPX pages, there master pages have the suffix .master), also have the suffix .cshtml, but usually they aren't rendered directly from the controller, however you must specify the layout of the page:

```
@{
  Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Then Razor will look for `_Layout.cshtml` in the current directory and the directory `/Views/Shared`, like any view. If you set `Layout = null;`, then the page won't have a layout.

This code can also be at `/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`, because by the convention, any code in this file will be run **before** the code in the view (so you can override the layout specified in this file from the view).

When Razor Engine should render a view with a layout, it renders only the layout. But, if when you call the method `RenderBody()`, it renders the view and puts it in the `RenderBody()` call's place.

There is a similar method, `RenderSection()`, which renders a single section of the view. Give a look on the `<head>` element of your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

The call to `RenderSection()` renders the section `scripts`. the parameter `required: false` specify that the casn be a view without the section `scripts`; Without it, such view will trigger a runtime error.

Now, please look the follow view:

```
<div>Some View</div>
```

The call to `RenderBody()` will be replaced by `<div>Some View</div>`.

However, if the view looks like as follows:

```
<div>Some View</div>

@section scripts {
  <script src="jsfile.js"></script>
}
```

Then, `RenderBody()` will be the same, but the call `RenderSection("scripts", ...)` will be replaced by `<script src="jsfile.js"></script>`. Sections enable you to create a main content, but also secondary contents - such as a header, special scripts/styles, etc.

Some comment: layouts can have layouts too - it enable you to create a nested page, for example in a company - the main layout, a special layout for the marketing class, a layout for the management sections...

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! The only solution I had found to disappear was this: `<div id = "main" style = "display: none">@RenderBody()</ div>`

Comment: @Dinho This isn't the best solution. You should change the layout only for change the uniform things, such as menus, footers, etc.. If you have a problem with the view, just find the view and change it (the default view is usually `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`).

Comment: This looks good, and thank you, but how does `RenderBody()` know which page to render? I *think* it renders the page that called the `_Layout`, correct?

Comment: "This looks good, and thank you, but how does RenderBody() know which page to render?"  <-- I'm wondering the same thing.